# How to find which column makes a table unique?

Tags: data-cleaning

I often work on community ecology data sets that I have to restructure to fit my template. They often have many columns:

- categorical columns describing the site such as `country`, `site`, `treatment`, `plot`, `subplot`, `latitude`, `longitude`
- columns that describe the date `year`, `month`, and `day`
- (sometimes) columns that contain measures like depth or temperature at the `site`, `plot` or `subplot` level
- and finally, the finest grain: the species observation with a `species` column and an `abundance` column.

Column names and data structures are not consistent from a data set to another and I want to restructure them to a consistent format. Since I'm interested in data at the `country` and `year` levels, I pool data together. To make sure that we have an equal number of samples per `country` and `year`, I constantly count and subsample `plot`s, `subplot`s, `month`s and `day`s.

Now my **problem** that I struggle to describe:

When I open the data set with all the columns, there are no redundant rows (hopefully...), I delete depth or temperature columns if any, still no redundant rows (hopefully...).

Now I want to identify the nestedness of `country`,`site`, `treatment`, `plot`, etc and `year`, `month` `day` columns ie I want to identify which column above the `species` `abundance` columns is making the table unique.

I would like to develop an R function, preferably using `data.table` but I don't know how to address my problem.

Any suggestion in form of title improvement, question improvement, a keyword to look up online or pseudo code would be very appreciated.